# Assign an AutomationId to ContentPresenter in a GridViewRowPresenter (ListView)

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to do coded UI testing with a ListView that is has a list of checkbox items.

Due to trouble with the coded UI code selecting the checkbox cell, I have been trying to add AutomationId to the controls, so that the coded UI test works.

I'm almost there, in snoop I can see that the UIItemCell does not have AutomationId set, but I can't figure out how to set it in my app.

[image: coded UI test builder window]

The UIItemCell is where I need to set AutomationId

I found with Snoop that it's the ContentPresenter

[image: Snoop control tree]

The ListView code is this complex, so I'll distill it a bit

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Height="194"
          Margin="53,123,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="424"
          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="listviewoption">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Description }" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

                        <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Bxaid1" >

                            <Grid AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Gxaid1">

                                <!-- This is used when GridView is put inside the ListView -->
                                <GridViewRowPresenter AutomationProperties.AutomationId="gvrp"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                <!-- ... -->
                            </Grid>

                        </Border>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="ListViewItemContainerStyle1"/>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>

        <GridView AutomationProperties.AutomationId="aid1">

            <GridViewColumn AutomationProperties.AutomationId="xc0"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OptionName, Converter={StaticResource CamelCaseConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Width="180"/>

            <GridViewColumn AutomationProperties.AutomationId="xc1"
                            Width="60">

                <GridViewRowPresenter AutomationProperties.AutomationId="pp" />

                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate  >
                        <CheckBox Name="x1"
                                  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="xaid1"
                                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                  Tag="{Binding OptionName}"
                                  IsChecked=""
                                  Padding="0"
                                  Margin="0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>

    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

There are some AutomationIds in there that haven't helped but are good points of reference; 'gvrp' is the GridViewRowPresenter [016] that holds the Content Presenter [017] that I want to put the id on, and 'xaid1' is the CheckBox inside the Content Presenter [017].

Please help before my head explodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it eventually with

```
<GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">

    <GridViewRowPresenter.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Name }"/>
        </Style>
    </GridViewRowPresenter.Resources>

</GridViewRowPresenter>
```

However, the automatically testing generated code (coded UI) still referenced the table column (even though it was redundant) which was the problem I was trying to avoid in the first place...

Anyway, it is possible to set the `AutomationId` in the `ContentPresenter` and in case it's helpful to anyone living in the future, here it is!